# modelling in google-datastore: use lists or separate entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

I'm stuck trying to implement a data model for an app to be deployed on AppEngine.

Here's an example of the model:

```
EntityName
  id:  1
  author:       'me'
  description:  'whatever'
  datetime:     2011 etc.
  events: [
    {location: [1,2], phase: ['A', 'B']},
    {location: [3,4], phase: ['C', 'B']},
    ... more events ...
  ]
```

Explanation:

- `EntityName` has a few attributes, and many `events`
- each `event` has a list of numbers (its `location`) and a list of strings (`phase`)

**How can this model be implemented in AppEngine?**  The data only needs to be searchable by `id`, `author`, `datetime`, and `description`.

---

What I've tried to figure out how to do (still going through the docs) *(sticking point in italics)*:

1. one table, `EntityName`, with `events` as a [`ListProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty)
   *this would require nested lists in one table ... not sure if that's possible*
2. two tables, `EntityName` and `Event`
   *needs a join, which I understand isn't directly possible*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't tables, exactly, but I think this should work for you

```
class EntityName(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty(...)

class Event(db.Model):
    entity_name = db.ReferenceProperty(EntityName, collection_name='events')
    location = db.StringListProperty()
    phase = db.StringListProperty()
```

Then...

```
e = EntityName(author='me', ...)
e.put()
event = Event(entity_name=e, location=...)
event.put()

for ev in e.events:
    print ev.location
    print ev.phase
```

[See the documentation for details](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html). You don't need to "do a join" because this isn't a SQL database. For your convenience, collection_name will create an iterator on the referenced side of a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have said "join" or "table", I'm not thinking in terms of AppEngine/DataStore models  or terminology ... for `location` you use a `StringListProperty` -- I thought there was a possibility to use list of different types.  Is that not commonly done?  And is `ReferenceProperty` also in `db`?

Comment: Yes, see the docs: ReferenceProperty is in the datastore API. There's only a StringListProperty, but you can just stores strings with integer in them. You can even inherit from StringListProperty to do the conversion automatically.

Comment: There's no need to break things out into two separate entities like this.

Comment: Why not, Nick? If an event has multiple attributes, a string list won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that only uses one model (i.e., Nick's idea):

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db

class EntityName(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()
    # ...
    event_locations = db.StringListProperty(indexed=False)
    event_phases    = db.StringListProperty(indexed=False)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        e = EntityName(author='me',
            event_locations=['1,2', '3,4'], event_phases=['A,B', 'C,D'] )
        e.put()

        q = EntityName.all().filter('author =', 'me')
        text = ''
        for en in q:
            for locations, phases in zip(en.event_locations, en.event_phases):
                text += "location=%s, phase=%s<br>" % (locations, phases)
        self.response.out.write(text)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Sample output:

```
location=1,2, phase=A,B
location=3,4, phase=C,D
```

Since [order is generally preserved](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling#Lists) in List and StringList properties, your locations and phases for an event can be matched up -- i.e., they have the same index in the two lists.

With one model you have to do a little more work splitting out each entry in the list, but you save on datastore reads and writes, since you only have one entity.